# Mouseenter mark only one active node in hierarchy

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouse

I have several nested div-s and I would like to mark only one of them active when the mouse is over that element. The following code isn't work for every situation.

Code sample:
`Red -> container`
`Green -> outer`
`Yellow -> inner`
`Blue ->active`

The most inner div with the mouse should have the blue background only.

It works only for very few interactions and most of the times it fails. What would be the best and less resource heavy solution for this problem?

```js
function markActive($el) {
  $el.addClass('active');
  $el.parent().triggerHandler('inactive');
}

function markInActive($el) {
  $el.removeClass('active');
  $el.parent().triggerHandler('active');
}

$('div').on({
  mouseenter: function() {
    markActive($(this));
  },
  mouseleave: function() {
    markInActive($(this));
  },
  inactive: function() {
    markInActive($(this));
  },
  active: function() {
    markActive($(this));
  }

});
```

```css
div {
  clear: left;
  float: left;
  padding-left:20px;
  height: 400px;
  background: #f00;
}
div div {
  height: 125px;
  background: #0f0;
}
div div div {
  width: 280px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #ff0;
}
div.active {
  background: #00f;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
      <span>Most inner #1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
      <span>Most inner #2</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
      <span>Most inner #3</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try with `mouseout` and `mouseover` events?

Comment: Good idea, I just tried it and it seems OK. Here is a fiddle, you could post it as an answer: https://jsfiddle.net/ddsxxeer/1/

Comment: Just did it. Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually what we do need is `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events, those aren't fired when user enters (ou leaves) a child element. In your case you need the old `mouseout` and `mouseover` events, that are trigged in that cases.

In the comments you've post a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ddsxxeer/1/

:)

Comment: One note which came after right after this problem. In my final code, I have absolute positioned element's inside the div-s - shows only when the mouse is over the element with mouseover mouseout -, but mouseout triggered if the mouse moved over the absolute positioned elements. So I have to use if(this.$element.find(e.relatedTarget).length == 0) to prevent mouseout for this case.